# EditTextPreference and screen rotation

Tags: android, rotation, screen, edittextpreference

I searched this place but couldn't find an answer which helped me: I have a settings activity which works with a PreferenceFragment. There is an EditTextPreference on one of the settings. It saves its value nicely. However, when I rotate the screen, the EditTextPreference disappears and the changes made are lost.

This is because the Activity is newly created. Got it.

I know I can use onSaveInstanceState to get the data entered, however, it's not clear to me how I can make the EditTextPreference appear again (in fact I added no coding for that, it's all happening via xml definition). Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange read the developer documentation this will help you.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, thanks, I read it once more. It states that _this technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications._ I don't think what I want to achieve is exotic as all other apps do it in the same way. I think I would need to work with the `onSaveInstanceState()` but this is a protected method of `EditTextPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. After some trial and error, I found something that worked for me:

I just added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the preferences activity in the manifest. The `EditText` does not disappear on orientation change and its content (the text) remains preserved.